# Passing bool to feed dict

Tags: tensorflow

So here is an example of using batch normalization over a 1-D input vector. Batch normalization is performed over 100 training examples `xTr`. I then want to test on say just 1 example later on `xTe`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import layers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bn = layers.batch_norm
    nFeats = 3 
    nObs = 100 
    xTr = np.random.rand(nObs,nFeats) # Train
    xTe = np.random.rand(1,nFeats) # Test
    bnTrain = tf.placeholder(tf.bool) 
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,nFeats])
    Y = bn(X,nFeats,is_training=bnTrain) # want to be able to change is_training via a feed_dict.
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        yTr_ = Y.eval(feed_dict={X:xTr,bnTrain:True})
        yTe_ = Y.eval(feed_dict={X:xTe,bnTrain:False})
```

But I can't pass a `tf.Tensor` to a function expecting a normal python bool. What is the best way of going about this so I can change a bool during a session.

Comment: Is the `bnTrain:True` in `feed_dict` you are talking about? I can run this code on my machine.

Comment: It was a version error, mine was previously 0.08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of the [`tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/higher_level_ops_for_building_neural_network_layers_#batch_norm) function is designed to accept a `tf.Tensor` as the `is_training` argument (although this fact doesn't appear to be documented), and looking at the revision history, it was added in the TensorFlow 0.10 release. If you are using an older version, please try upgrading to the latest release (currently 0.12), and your existing code should work. Among other improvements, it contains a fused implementation of batch normalization that should make a significant performance improvement.